# How to find the center line (or the skeleton) of these kind of shapes in opencv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the center line or the skeleton of some "stick like" objects. Like showed in image.

[image]

Lines I want to fine are kind of like yellow lines showed below. Actually I want to estimate the length, diameter and volume of the whole stuff and so on based on that center line.

[image]

I found there are some methods to calculate the skeleton in opencv like the following link. But it is too slow to do that from the binary image. I would like to ask does anyone know some faster method, maybe based on the contour only? Thanks!

[slow mathod for skeleton](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/)

Comment: there are many techniques, some perform better than morphological  skeletonization, some worse. which alternatives have you tried so far? and what is it you are actually interested in? maybe you don't even need the center line for that asparagus (I guess)?

Comment: Isn't half the perimeter a sufficient approximation for length here? maybe subtract a value for thickness. or do you want to measure these things down to sub millimeter range? :D

Comment: @Piglet Oh, thanks a lot for your comment. All the methods I tried are similar to the link in the description( i.e. morphological skeletonization). I also tried to do that manually myself. I cut each asparagus into small pieces and find the center points one by one. But the algorithm I wrote is becoming more and more complicated. I think it is not wise to carry on. Could you please tell me the names of other techniques? So that I could do more studying. Actually I want to approximate the actual length of the asparagus and estimate their volumes, too..

Comment: just google "center line blob" or similar keywords. you'll find things like that: http://microboone-docdb.fnal.gov/cgi-bin/RetrieveFile?docid=732&filename=12-11-09-CAnderson-CVCenterlineExtraction.pdf&version=1  but as I said, if you only need the length down to a few millimeters you may not even need that center line.

Comment: @Piglet ach, I also want to estimate the avarage diameter. So the direction of the center line is also interesting. Then I guess when I have the center line, I have all. :) Thanks again for helping me to modify this question.

Comment: @Piglet super! I'll google it. And use the half whole length substract thickness to get the length sounds also interesting. I'll consider that:):)

Comment: Hope this will helpful for you: http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/skel.html

Comment: @AndreySmorodov thanks a lot, the ideas look like exactly what I need. I'll go through it.